# Java Generics - Class or Class<? extends SomeClass>

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection

I am writing a program which will use Java reflection (i.e., `Class.forName()`) to dynamically create class instance based on user's input.  One requirement is that the instance my program creates must extend one specific Class I defined, called it `SomeClass`.  My question is: for storing this class type, should I use bounded generic, `Class<? extends SomeClass>`, or simply unbounded generic, `Class`?  I found some Java books say that Class is one of the good practices for using unbounded wildcard generic, but I am wondering whether this apply to the situation in my program.

Please feel free to let me know if you found my question is not clear enough or some information is needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `Class<? extends SomeClass>` because that's what generics are for.

At the time when you invoke `Class.forName`, check to see if it `SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom` the new class. Otherwise, you should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or `ClassCastException`.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, calling [`asSubclass(SomeClass.class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) will do this for you.

For example:

```
public SomeClass instantiate(String name)
  throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    Class<?> raw = Class.forName(name);

    //throws ClassCastException if wrong
    Class<? extends SomeClass> generic = raw.asSubclass(SomeClass.class);

    // do what you want with `generic`

    return generic.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: @Vulcan yes, but that's not what OP specified. He wants them all to extend `SomeClass`.

Comment: It would be cleaner to just use [`asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass\(java.lang.Class\)) instead of checking `isAssignableFrom` and then throwing an exception yourself.

Comment: Also, there's still no justification for the unchecked cast - your helper method should just return `SomeClass` and not be generic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  One follow up question is that I found asSubclass may throw ClassCastException, does that mean this function should also throws ClassCastException?

Comment: @Yueh It could, or it could not. `ClassCastException` is a runtime (unchecked) exception, so you have three choices [A] don't declare it, [B] declare it so your users know it can be thrown (nicer in my opinion), or [C] `try`-`catch` it and handle it yourself.

Comment: For an analogy, just because a method can throw the unchecked `NullPointerException` doesn't mean *any method that uses that method* must declare it to be thrown as well. If that were the case, pretty much all methods would `throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException`.